# Something Weird About SQL Server Database

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have a database that I am writing select statements on.

I decided to alter the table and add (example) a Fruit Number which works perfectly.

I use an insert into statement to add values to the Fruit Number column and that also works.

**Now comes the problem:**

A few minutes later it is underlined in red and says invalid column in my insert statement but when I select * it is displayed correctly with values inside.

Now I use select Fruit Number and it does not work. The funny part is when I go to a new query/page and do the select Fruit Number there it works.

**For some reason I cannot select Fruit Number when I do it in the same query my database is in so I have to add a new query every time I select something from an alter table.**

I tried closing and opening it again but its still the same thing. Any ideas?

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+R to refresh intellisense in SQL Server

Comment: Hey Tom, welcome to Stack Overflow! I'm a bit worried that this question won't get you a good answer. It would be helpful if you could supply, perhaps, an example of the query, and particularly if you could break the post into a couple paragraphs. It's a small thing, but it goes a long ways in letting potential answerers understand your problem. I say this just because I know what it's like to have that kind of confusing problem, and I want to make sure you get a good answer as fast as possible.

Comment: Just restart management studio. Management studio loaded the columns in the table for intellisense once when it started and hasn't updated yet. It's just the syntax highlighting part, and Management Studio is NOT the database; just one tool of several possible for connecting to it.

Comment: Also, why is this tagged "mysql". You do realize that MySql is a completely different database engine, right?

Comment: How do I restart it? If you mean hitting the X button and waiting a few seconds then opening it again, I tried that and failed. I also restarted my laptop but it doesn't work either. I actually tried running the code with the red underline and it actually works. FruitNumber is displayed with all the correct values but my insert statement and select statement is still in red. Intellisense is being stubborn for some reason.

Comment: Can you show the query you're trying to run, tom?

Comment: is your column really named "Fruit Number" ... including the blank? make sure than to put [] around the column name everywhere you use it ... or use FruitNumber als column name

Answer (score 0):

I found out that there is no fix to it. The main reason why the code runs even with the red underline is because the management studio is looking at two different parts. If you do a select in a new query the intellisense looks at the entire database as a whole but if you do a select in the same query your database is in then the intellisense only looks at the tables you have created which does not include the alter table statements. Any form of refreshing will not work because of how intellisense works. Its fine as long as the code runs. I can just ignore the annoying red line.